# How to enable folding of eclipse style block comments in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, comments, block-comments

Is there anyway to get Android Studio to show the folding +/- icon for Eclipse style block comments, for example either,

/*
 * Here is a block comment.
 */

or

/*
   Here is another comment.
 */

I only get the fold/expand icons for blocks that begin with the single line comment style "//".

Answer (score 0):

You can get Android Studio to show the folding +/- icon for arbitrary block. 
Select the part you want to fold and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>